# Empty result when calculating erro rate ratio

Tags: prometheus, thanos

I need to compare the error rate of two different HTTP client versions with that of a legacy client, for each possibile combination of status code and client version.

As an example of what I'm trying to achieve, consider that I have the following results for the *legacy* client:

| *legacy* HTTP response status | % of responses with that status |
| --- | --- |
| 401 | 0.02 |
| 503 | 0.01 |

and the following results for *v1*:

| *v1* HTTP response status | % of responses with that status |
| --- | --- |
| 401 | 0.01 |
| 503 | 0.04 |

then I want a query that would give me the following results:

| status | *v1* / *legacy* error rate ratio |
| --- | --- |
| 401 | 0.5 |
| 503 | 4 |

So, I want the query to show me that the error rate for *v1* when you consider the 503 status code is 4x what I have for *legacy*.

I have a metric `http_response` that has the following labels:

- `status`: the HTTP response status code
- `version`: the HTTP client version (whose values can be `legacy`, `v1` or `v2`)

I came up with the following query, but I get a "Empty query result" response when I try to run it through Thanos:

```
sum(rate(http_response{status="[45]..", version=~"v2|v1"}[15m])) by (version, status) /  on(version) 
group_left
sum(rate(http_response{version=~"v2|v1"}[15m])) by (version) / on (status) 

group_left

sum(rate(http_response{status=~"[45]..", version="legacy"}[15m])) by (version, status) /  on(version) 
group_left
sum(rate(http_response{version="legacy"}[15m])) by (version)
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Each query that calculates the error rate for each client individually does return, for example:

```
sum(rate(http_response{status="[45]..", version=~"v2|v1"}[15m])) by (version, status) /  on(version) 
group_left
sum(rate(http_response{version=~"v2|v1"}[15m])) by (version) / on (status)
```

gives me:

| result | value |
| --- | --- |
| `{status="503", version="v1"}` | 0.018 |
| `{status="503", version="v2"}` | 0.033 |
| `{status="400", version="v1"}` | 0.002 |

while the one that determines the ratio for the `legacy` client gives me:

| result | value |
| --- | --- |
| `{status="503", version="legacy"}` | 0.016 |
| `{status="400", version="legacy"}` | 0 |
| `{status="500", version="legacy"}` | 0.001 |

But I can't manage to make the original query work. I wonder if this 0 in the 400 status code line would be a problem.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? On which step do you begin loosing values?

Comment: Also, are you sure `rate` is what you wanted to use? Shouldn't it maybe be `increase? 15m seems a bit unusual for rate.

Comment: hi @markalex I've broken down the original query and edited the question with the individual results. I'm not able to get results only when I combine both queries.

As for you suggestion switching to `increase`, I think it's not an option for me as I'm really interested in comparing the per-second rate of errors.

Comment: Presumably labels in the last table have a typo and all versions there are `legacy`?

Comment: You're right, fixed it. thanks